# Error on caravel source code build - no previously included files matching *.pyo

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to build the source code of caravel.
Following the instructions I have installed the front end dependencies using npm.

on python setup.py install I am getting error:

> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere
> in distribution warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd'
> found anywhere in distribution
> numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c.src:7:29: fatal error:
> npy_math_common.h: No such file or directory  #include
> "npy_math_common.h"

I tried running with python3.

I am running this on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I missed on installing some numpy libraries.

sudo apt-get install python-numpy

sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev

After installing the above pakages my issue got resolved.
Caravel is running fine.